# Is it possible to identify data type with Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Here is the situation: I use Matlab to read a file that a spectrometer created. To do so, I use the following simple code :

```
id=fopen(filename, 'r', 'l');       
[realimag, ~] = fread(id, 'int32');
fclose(id);
```

The problem I have is that, now I have a second spectrometer that produces file that need to be read using 'double' in the fread function. So I have to change the code every time... Is there a way to know what is the data type so I would not have to change the code every time ?

In advance thank you.

Comment: A file filled with `double` values is just a sequence of bits that will be identical to the right sequence of twice as many `int32` values. So is this really the question you need to answer? You could instead solve the problem by relying on user input in the process, but a more convenient input than "change the code every time", or you could use clues from the file name to decide which spectrometer the file came from. Otherwise you will have to make an educated guess from the size of the numbers which `precision` value produces the most believable results.

Comment: With that in mind, the least significant bits in a `double` value and a pair of `int32` values are in quite different places so unless the values from your second spectrometer can plausibly have greater magnitudes than the range of `int32` (±2^31) then if the files have enough values an educated guess should be quite easy as files read using the wrong precision will almost certainly contain infeasible values.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The files have the same name as there are created by the same software (just different versions), and I would like to avoid user input as other people than me will use the code, and they may not know enough to do the right choice. But you made me think that I may have a way to know the size of the 'realimag'. So I will read the file twice and select the one that have the good size. Thank you for the idea !

Answer (score 2):

`fread` is to read files interpreting them as binary files, i.e. as a sequence of bits. Therefore you can read a binary flow of data and interpret it as you like, and you cannot know how to read it, unless someone tells you how.

Try using those commands to read from a file with the following content

```
àéèìòù
```

It will work, and you will get

```
>> realimag

realimag =

  -320280096
   168491506
```

which has no meaning at all.

If you read it with

```
[realimag, ~] = fread(id, 'char');
```

then you'll get

```
realimag =

   224
   233
   232
   236
   242
   249
    10
    10
```

and guess what?

```
>> int32('àéèìòù')

ans =

  1×6 int32 row vector

   224   233   232   236   242   249
```

what are those two tens, then? Well,

```
>> char(10)

ans =

    '
     '
```

a new line.

This is just to say that when you read a binary file, it is your choice how to read it.

Clearly, if someone tells you that the first *n* bytes contain a string which tells you how to read the rest of the file, then it's a different story. But, again, you have to know, or someone has to tell you.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately there are no strings at the begining of the file to telle me how to read it. I know I have to read it the way I am beacause of the documentation of the software that creates these files (same software for both but different versions...). But the comment of Will made me think that I may have a way to know how long the 'realimag' should be, I will try to read the file both ways and select the one that have the correct size.

Comment: @Ronicent, I've never said that there are/should be strings or anything special in your file. My point is that the answer to "is it possible to identify data type in a file when reading it bitwise?" is "no", regardless of the language, for the simple reason that the value of any data type is, in the end, just a sequence of bits. Therefore, unless you are able to judge if interpreting it as a sequence of `double`s is better than interpreting it as a sequence of `char`s (or `unit8`, or ...), you can't know how to read it.